# Why does Subversion consider this a conflict?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, branching-and-merging

I am trying to practice using a Subversion branch for development and merging it into the trunk.  I'm using the TortoiseSVN GUI for Subversion.

In my trunk, I added a comment as the first line of a file:

```
// Comment added to test Subversion versioning
```

Then, on a different computer, I checked out the project, created a new branch named RobDevelopment, and added another comment line, so the file now began with:

```
// Comment added to test Subversion versioning
// Comment from RobDevelopment branch
```

On that machine, I then switched my project's branch to the trunk and used merge to bring in the change I made in the development branch.  Instead of updating the trunk to add the new comment from the development branch, Subversion complained that the file was conflicted.  When I looked at the conflict, instead of showing me either of the comments, TortoiseSVN showed me three lines of question marks.

Why was Subversion unable to merge my new comment?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that you changed line endings or encoding when you modified the file in your branch. Therefore, you need to check EOLs and encoding.

[image]